# Изучение 3D MAX

Tags: 3dsmax

Подскажите,пожалуйста,объязательно ли нужно знать ArchiCAD и AutoCAD,чтобы начать изучить  3D MAX.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет конечно.

А вот художественный вкус и хоть что-то от школьного курса геометрии - не повредит)) Дерзайте!